# Issue with Google Sheeet API

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to make web service to write into GoogleSheet API with PHP.

for that, I am following the documentation of google console

[Link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)

and make below code

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
 throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

function getClient()
{
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
  $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
  $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

  $tokenPath = 'token.json';
  if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
  }

  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
            throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
        }
    }
    if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
        mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
  return $client;
}


$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

$spreadsheetId = 'XXXX';
$range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = [["This","is","a","new","row"],];
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
  "values" =>$values
]);
$params = [
  "valueInputOption" => "RAW",
   "insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"
];
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append(
  $spreadsheetId,
  $range,
  $body,
  $params
);
```

But when I run this code this gives me the error which is given below.

> [25-Nov-2019 01:53:03 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This application must be run on the command line.' in Google_sheet/quickstart.php:5
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}

```
thrown in Google_sheet/quickstart.php on line 5
```

can you please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says it clearly:

> This application must be run on the command line.

So, this means you are not running it using the command line, you are trying to access it using the browser. If you do as the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) says:

```
php quickstart.php
```

then it will work.

---

**Why am I seeing this exception when accessing using the browser?**

Because of this lines placed at the beginning of your code:

```php
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
 throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}
```

**What if I want to run it on the browser?**

Just remove those lines and you'll be able to run the script using the browser.