# issue with writing in google sheet with API

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use google sheet API to write in google sheet API.

For that, I am using below code

```
$spreadsheetId = 'XXXX';
$range = "Zoho Emails 2";
$values = [["This","is","a","new","row"],];
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
   "values" =>$values
]);
$params = [
   `valueInputOptions` => "RAW"
];
$insert = [
   "insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"
];
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append(
  $spreadsheetId,
  $range,
  $body,
  $params,
  $insert
);
```

But when I run This code this code gives me below error

```
[26-Nov-2019 22:45:36 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' 
with message '(append) unknown parameter: ''' in 
/Google_sheet/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php:147
Stack trace:
#0 /Google_sheet/vendor/google/apiclient- 
services/src/Google/Service/Sheets/Resource/SpreadsheetsValues.php(65): 
Google_Service_Resource->call('append', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
#1 /Google_sheet/quickstart.php(99): Google_Service_Sheets_Resource_SpreadsheetsValues- 
>append('1k8sR-aV8O5W7jP...', 'Zoho Emails 2', Object(Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange), Array, 
Array)
#2 {main}
thrown in /Google_sheet/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php on line 147
```

But I don't understand why this error occurs.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
$params = [
   `valueInputOptions` => "RAW"
];
$insert = [
   "insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"
];
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append(
  $spreadsheetId,
  $range,
  $body,
  $params,
  $insert
);
```

#### To:

```
$params = [
  "valueInputOption" => "RAW",
  "insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"
];
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append(
  $spreadsheetId,
  $range,
  $body,
  $params
);
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for the Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

### Added:

When the script in [the link of your another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59028484/7108653) you provided in the discussion is used, the whole script reflected my modified script is as follows. Before you run the script, please set the variables of `$spreadsheetId` and `$range`. Before you run the script, please confirm `credentials.json` and delete the file of `token.json`. Then, run the script. At that time, please authorize again. By this, I think that the script works.

The scope is changed from `Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY` to `Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS`.

#### Whole script:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
 throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

function getClient()
{
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
  $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
  $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

  $tokenPath = 'token.json';
  if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
  }

  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
            throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
        }
    }
    if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
        mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
  return $client;
}


$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

$spreadsheetId = "###"; // Spreadsheet ID
$range = "###"; // Sheet name

$values = [["This","is","a","new","row"],];
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
   "values" =>$values
]);
$params = [
  "valueInputOption" => "RAW",
  "insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"
];
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append(
  $spreadsheetId,
  $range,
  $body,
  $params
);
```

Comment: Thank you for giving answer but when I tried this I have received an error with PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Comment: @MNJ Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From the error message, the scopes which are used for your access token cannot be used for putting the values to Spreadsheet. So how about changing the scope for your script? For example if you are using the quickstart script, how about modifying to `$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);`? When you modified the scopes, please remove `token.json` file and reauthorize the scopes again. By this, you can use the access token including the new scopes. If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: @MNJ I thought that in your current script, the scope might be `$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) If it's so, please modify to `$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);`. And please delete `token.json` and run the script again.

Comment: I have done exactly the same which you say but still, I have receive the error :

Comment: [26-Nov-2019 23:40:14 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'missing the required redirect URI' in /home/webrsqco/public_html/splitscreenapp.com/Google_sheet/vendor/google/auth/src/OAuth2.php:651
Stack trace:
#0 /Google_sheet/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(344): Google\Auth\OAuth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri(Array)

Comment: @MNJ Thank you for replying. I think that unfortunately, the reason of your new error is not due to the script. That is due to your credential. So can you confirm your credential file (`credentials.json`) again? If you cannot understand about this, how about downloading `credentials.json` again and use it? By the way, please don't worry. Because I could confirm that when the authorization was done, the modified script worked fine.

Comment: Thank You for replying I have just checked my token.json file and my full code which is given in quickstart.php which is available in google documentation  and as per the documentation token.json is including in quickstart.php for get access token and for other parameters

Comment: and in access token file there is one parameter "scope":"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/spreadsheets.readonly" which is readonly

Comment: so I think the issue is with this read-only scope is I add token.json file for all access token in my folder